# Federate Skype with Open Fire

Tags: openfire, skype, federation

Is there anyone who knows how to federate skype with open fire. I have almost studied every link related to this topic but haven't found a solution yet.

If anyone has solved this problem then please do help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skype is not open for any kind of federation. The protocol is closed, Skype binaries heavily obfuscated. Microsoft has deprecated Skype automation APIs and offer only very limited machine-to-machine interaction with Skype.

Comment: I came across Kraken cloned plugin with skype but I am not able to build it to generate a jar file, can you help me out in this.
This is link please do check it out.
https://github.com/lemmy/kraken-gateway

Thanks

Comment: Don't bother https://github.com/taksan/skype-java-api/issues/40#issuecomment-21045393 - please find an alternative for Skype which is owned by a company of which API support you can rely. Or even better, run your own XMPP server.